# set_camera_info Unavailable with ROS on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: python, ros, camera-calibration

When I'm running this, and click calibration then commit. show error like this. please help me to solve this problem thank you.

```
rosrun camera_calibration cameracalibrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 image:=/usb_cam/image_raw usb_cam:=/start_capture
```

the error is:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camera_calibration/camera_calibrator.py",
> line 247, in on_mouse
>     if self.do_upload():   File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/camera_calibration/camera_calibrator.py",
> line 204, in do_upload
>     response = self.set_camera_info_service(info)   File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py",
> line 435, in __call__
>     return self.call(*args, **kwds)   File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py",
> line 495, in call
>     service_uri = self._get_service_uri(request)   File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/impl/tcpros_service.py",
> line 463, in _get_service_uri
>     raise ServiceException("service [%s] unavailable"%self.resolved_name) rospy.service.ServiceException:
> service [/camera/set_camera_info] unavailable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do `rosservice list` can you see the `/camera/set_camera_info` service running?
Please, update your answer with the results from `rostopic list` and `rosservice list`.